# Changing option value in dropdown item using excel vba

Tags: excel, dojo, vba

I am new learner to programming and new to excel-VBA as well and learning scraping through it. I am trying to programmatically change the color on a website having below html

```
<div><select id="Color" name="Color" data-dojo- type="dijit.form.FilteringSelect"><option value="ORANGE">Orange</option><option value="GREEN" selected="selected">Green</option><option value="YELLOW">Yellow</option></select></div>


IE1.document.getElementByID("Color").Value = "Orange"
IE1.document.getElementByID("Color").Focus
IE1.document.getElementByID("Color").Click
```

After doing this I can see the "Orange" being written on the dropdown on webpage but when I submit the form on website then it considers the default selected "Green" value and not the changed value which is "Orange". Also tried focus and click but still no luck.

Could you please help me out here? I tried searching for any existing VBA solution but could not find any. I think dijit.form.FilteringSelect is what it is making it unique.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the value using dijit tools.
The first command grabs the widget from dojo's widget registry.
They second command changes it.

```
var fs = dijit.registry.byId("Color");
fs.set("value","Orange");
```

Comment: Hi tik27, thanks for your response. But this seems to be dojo specific code and doesn't look like would work in excel-vba. I am specifically looking for a vba based solution.

Comment: Guys, need help...bit desperately actually..I am trying to figure out but not able to proceed at all.

Comment: IE1.document.getElementByID("Color").Value = "Orange"
IE1.document.getElementByID("Color").nextElementSibling.value = "<OrangeID>"

Comment: Thank you @tik27. I think this code is setting the hidden value to correct code, however seems like there is some other code which needs to trigger in order to change the other fields based on this selection. Will keep you posted on my progress on this. I am able to make the other fields toggle based on color selection, but only via Sendkeys method which does not work in minimized mode or when IE.Visible is False. Thank you again.